# Create file in directory

Tags: php

I am trying to create a file in a sub directory but it is not creating it

```
$tempFilename = "xml/tempfile.xml";
    if(file_exists($tempFilename))
            {    
                unlink($tempFilename);
            }
        $file = fopen($tempFilename,"w");
        $fileTemplate = ($xml);
```

Comment: the `xml` folder exists?

Comment: What do you want to do with `$fileTemplate = ($xml);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fwrite.php) :

```
$tempFilename = "xml/tempfile.xml";
// Test if directory exists.
$dirname = dirname($tempFilename);
if (!is_dir($dirname))
{
    mkdir($dirname);
}
if(file_exists($tempFilename)){    
     unlink($tempFilename);
}
$file = fopen($tempFilename,"w");

// Write what you need
fwrite($file, 'content of my file');
fclose($file);
```

Comment: The file should be created as soon as you open it, you don't need to write anything into it. If you don't write anything, you get an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

```
file_put_contents($tempFilename, '23');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

first you need to create directory

```
$path = '/xml';
mkdir($path, 0777, true);
$tempFilename = "/xml/tempfile.xml";
if(file_exists($tempFilename))
        {    
            unlink($tempFilename);
        }
    $file = fopen($tempFilename,"w");
   fwrite($file, '23');
fclose($fp);
```